# Linq put Include inside select new

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this linq query and I want to get a dictionary, the value is a collection of entities, and I want to use an include for this list.

```
var keys = (from e in ctx.Events
            where (e.DeletedFlag == null || e.DeletedFlag == false) &&
            e.ModuleID == moduleId &&
            e.ParentID == null && 
            e.EventType == Core.Enum.EventType.Menu
            select new { 
                         Key = e,
                         Values = (from v in ctx.Events
                                   where (v.DeletedFlag == null || v.DeletedFlag == false) &&
                                   v.ModuleID == moduleId &&
                                   v.ParentID == e.PublicationID
                                   select v).Include(v => v.Document).Include(v => v.EventTAF).Include(v => v.Appointment)
                           }).ToList();
```

When I execute this query I get an error saying that linq does not recognize Include method.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having an inner query you can create two outer queries and then join them together:

```
var events = from e in ctx.Events
             where (e.DeletedFlag == null || e.DeletedFlag == false) &&
                 e.ModuleID == moduleId &&
                 e.ParentID == null && 
                 e.EventType == Core.Enum.EventType.Menu
                 select e;

var values = from v in ctx.Events
             where (v.DeletedFlag == null || v.DeletedFlag == false) &&
                 v.ModuleID == moduleId
             select v;
//TODO add Includes to values query

var query = from e in events
            join v in values
            on e.PublicationID equals v.ParentID into children
            select new
            {
                Key = e,
                Values = children,
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Directly to your question, if the Include Linq to Entities extension method is not present in the namespace, you need to ensure that a reference to EF is present (likely already true) and using namespace declarations:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Objects;
```

Comment: He's getting a runtime, and not compile time, error.  The compiler recognizes them, so this isn't the issue, but the query provider throws a runtime exception because it doesn't know how to handle `Include` calls on inner queries.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I didn't get that from the question.  The question says Linq, but it's Linq to Entities and which data store is being used is unspecified.  I've upvoted your answer because your reasoning and explanation are great given a runtime exception.

Comment: The question states: "When I execute this query" which is the reason you can tell that it's a runtime error, not a compile time error.  The question is also tagged `entity-framework` so we know it's not LINQ-to-objects.